# How To Use Flex on Windows

Tags: c, windows, lex, flex-lexer

I apologize if this is a dumb question, but I have 0 experience with this tool and wanted to know if I'm going about using it properly. I've downloaded flex which, upon compiling my lex file, produces a C file which then needs to be compiled separately. Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: In a previous life I had to hack on a project running on SCO Unix and Windows NT (or was it still 98?). What I did in the end was to run bison and flex on my Linux box, and compile on SCO and Windows. Not exactly elegant, but got the job done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to set up a Visual Studio project that uses `flex` as a custom build step in order to automatically invoke `flex` and then compile the generated file.  I taught a compilers course last summer and we have [instructions on how to get `flex` and a sample project file](http://www.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/) available on the archived course website.  You should look under the announcement labeled "Visual Studio Starter Files for PP1."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Using Win flex-bison with visual studio is quite easier and straightforward. You can find it at [Win Flex-Bison](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winflexbison/).